# Determine if there are commits to merge on a branch

Tags: bash, git

I have a script that auto merges a feature branch into master. It runs periodically.

I want the script to check that the feature branch does in fact have commits to be merged. If there are no commits the script should exit.

I’ve tried the following:

```
git rev-list --count HEAD
```

Run while on the feature branch with no commits this is returning a value of 1, so the script doesn’t exit, even though it should because there are no commits to merge.

Is there a better way to determine if there are commits to merge?

[Update] - using a feature branch called test which has no commits

Tried:

```
git rev-list --count master..
```

Resulted in error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Tried:

```
git rev-list --count master
```

Resulted in error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Tried:

```
git rev-list --count master..test
```

Resulted in error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'master..test': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

Comment: To count commits mergable to master checked out, specify master as the base of your count: `git rev-list --count master..`

Comment: Thanks @jthill - Think I tried that and got a path spec error, but I will give it another try later today

Comment: Any idea why my question got downvoted?

Comment: @jthill I tried several variations of your suggested answer, I could not get any of them to successfully complete - see updated answer for the commands ran and the errors I got

Comment: @vy218, `git rev-list` should definitely work. Looks like you may not have checkout master branch. Can you post the output of `git branch -a`?